Are stainless steel bowls better option for dogs?
I've alway took for axiom the fact that (properly and regularly cleaned) bowl made of stainless steel is the standard.
However today I asked myself - why in that case I as a human being not using stainless steel cups but rather sticking to porcelain, ceramics and glass.
My question is - is there any material that is generally more preferred for feeding dogs compared to other materials.

Dogs sometimes tend to bat their bowls around so something unbreakable is handy. Also as a human being, I've had much worse utencils than stainless, and many places and cultures do tend to use metal plates and such.

The main requirement for pet food bowls is that they must be non-porous and hygienic. A wood bowl or unglazed porcelain bowl would soak up bits of food and saliva and become quite stinky and gross.
Throughout history, humans have used a wide variety of materials for crockery like glass, different metals and clays (with or without an added glaze like enamel), but also plant matter like wood, big leaves or grass (bamboo). You'll see that most plant-based crockery is used only for a short time, while most metal or glazed crockery is designed for long-term use.
You could apply the same logic to pet food bowls and feed your dog from a banana leaf or a halved bamboo stem, but you'd probably like to replace this "bowl" quite often.
The other options like glass, porcellain or stoneware have the unfortunate tendency to break, so a metal dish seems the most durable alternative. And since our modern society preferres cheap mass-manufactured items, most people end up using stainless steel bowls to feed their pets.
However, humans have additional wants and needs like putting hot food on their plates and keeping it warm. Metal bowls and plates tend to be too hot to handle when the food is hot and cool the food down too quickly.

Your answer is well written, so I don't really want to write a whole new answer, but I think besides being non-porous and durable, metal is perhaps the most common material because it can be formed into the classic dog bowl shape, that is, the bowl with a wide, hollow base.  This prevents spills.  Other materials like ceramic cannot be made into that shape.  But on the other hand, metal isn't microwave safe, and it might collect mineral deposits from your tap water.
